# The server's get() endpoints aren't functioning properly

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, server

I am currently migrating a legacy server application code. On the new server, everything is functioning as expected, except for the `get()` endpoints in the API. It appears that the endpoint is not properly interpreting the request parameters.

```
public function lst(Request $request) {
        $response = [];

        return response()->json($request);
```

[image]

As was recommend by @silver i tried:

```
public function lst(Request $request)
    {
        $response = [];
        return response()->json(['all' => $request->all(), 'input' => $request->input('CodigoArmario'), 'request' => request('CodigoArmario') ] );
```

And i got:

```
{
"all": {
    "query_string": null
},
"input": null,
"request": null
```

}

Obs: The parameter key is okay.

The application utilizes php 7.4, laravel 6 and my nginx settings is the following:

```
server {
        server_name serverwebsitename.com;
        root /var/www/serverwebsitename/public/;

        if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*)$ )
        {
                return 301 https://$1$request_uri;
        }

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

        index index.html index.php;

        charset utf-8;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?query_string;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        error_page 404 /index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
                deny all;
        }

        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/serverwebsitename.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/serverwebsitename.com/privkey.pem;
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name serverwebsitename.com www.serverwebsitename.com;

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

I conducted some tests, including importing the server database to my local environment (7.4-apache docker image) and running endpoint tests, which yielded positive results. Additionally, I attempted to insert a localhost database into the production environment, but encountered the same issue in the `get()` endpoints.

I attempted to resolve the issue by removing the vendor directory and reinstalling dependencies using Composer, but unfortunately, I did not observe any positive results.

Comment: `return $response()` - that looks like strange stuff if `$response = []`. Also, are you sure this is only happening with nginx, and not with Apache?

Comment: Finally, keep in mind that Laravel 6 is EOL since more than a year. Please upgrade your application to ensure that it still receives security-related bugfixes - and maybe your problem also got fixed in the meantime

Comment: @NicoHaase It's worth noting that my localhost Docker image is running smoothly with Apache2, and all functions well. However, on the server, which operates with Nginx, the issue persists.

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes, you're absolutely correct. Our team is currently in the process of upgrading the legacy application.

Comment: The code you've shared works? That looks strange to me, as `$response()` shouldn't do anything meaningful. Also, if the `get()` endpoint makes problems, why not share it's code?

Comment: what do you get if you do `return response()->json(['all' => $request->all(), 'input' => $request->input('CodigoArmario'), 'request' => request('CodigoArmario') ] );`

Comment: also what do you get if you simply do `return response()->json( $_REQUEST );`  ?

Comment: @NicoHaase i apologize for the confusion. In my Stack Overflow question, I mistakenly used '$response()' incorrectly. I have since corrected the query and included information about the local server(php7.4-apache docker image).

Comment: Odd that it's returning `query_string: null` since there's nothing that would show the phrase `query_string`.

Comment: @silver, i got the following json response:                                                                                       {
    "all": {
        "query_string": null
    },
    "input": null,
    "request": null
}

Comment: what about returning php global variable `$_REQUEST` ? better you install [clockwork](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork) and check the request data from there and check if there's any middleware messing with the data

Comment: @silver                                                                                                                                                                           I made                                                                                                                                      return response()->json(["Request" => $_REQUEST]);
And i got: {
    "Request": {
        "query_string": ""
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in your nginx configuration. The reason you see `'query_string' => null` in the response is because you overwrite the actual query string with the `query_string` string in your nginx config. You miss a `$` before `query_string`.

You can fix the problem by adding the missing `$` character or try replacing the following line in your configuration with the line below for a cleaner result.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?query_string;
```

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
```

For a detailed explanation you can see [the nginx documentation about try_files](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).